# Can Scanner in Java read text from a dialog box

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Scanner can only get input from system console? not be able to get from any dialog window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

A [Scanner](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) can read text from any object which implements the [Readable](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Readable.html) interface.

That includes `BufferedReader`, `CharArrayReader`, `CharBuffer`, `FileReader`, `FilterReader`, `InputStreamReader`, `LineNumberReader`, `PipedReader`, `PushbackReader`, and `StringReader` (from the `Readable` javadoc).  Unfortunately, that does not include any dialog windows.

The easiest way to hook a dialog window to a `Scanner` would probably be to build a `Scanner` using the constructor that takes a `String`, passing the user input from the dialog directly to the `Scanner`.

Comment: It would certainly be possible to configure a dialog window to flow data throw an InputStream, which could then be hooked to a Scanner.

Comment: Certainly possible.  There are so many more straightforward ways to get user input from a dialog, that I've never considered this possibility before.

Comment: Certainly true.  I think the root of the original question may simply be a lack of knowledge or understanding about the alternatives.  I have certainly observed - recently, even - Scanner being used as the first option for input in a situation where it was clearly not the appropriate choice.

Comment: Also, side comment - why make a StringReader?  Scanners can already be created directly on Strings; the additional layer would only add overhead.

Comment: @Greg:  Right again.  I've never used that constructor before.  :)  I think the reason for the question might be so that they can use some of Scanner's convenience methods for parsing input.

Answer (score 1):

No; a [Scanner](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) may be created for any number of possible inputs: Files, InputStreams, ReadableByteChannels, Strings, and anything that supports the Readable interface.  See the [Constructor Summary](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#constructor_summary).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Scanner on a dialog box or label by first getting the text and scanning that.

```
String text = input.getText();
Scanner scan = new Scanner(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried with the example given at [Best way to determine the total number of words of a file in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277143/best-way-to-determine-the-total-number-of-words-of-a-file-in-java#277190): just replace `new File("my-text-file.txt")` with a String variable, and it works...

So if you get the textual content of the component into a String, you can use Scanner.