# Counting number of words in a file

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, io

I'm having a problem counting the number of words in a file. The approach that I am taking is when I see a space or a newLine then I know to count a word.

The problem is that if I have multiple lines between paragraphs then I ended up counting them as words also.  If you look at the readFile() method you can see what I am doing.

Could you help me out and guide me in the right direction on how to fix this?

Example input file (including a blank line):

```
word word word
word word

word word word
```

Comment: An intimidating number of duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+word+count

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277143/whats-the-best-way-to-determine-the-total-number-of-words-of-a-file-in-java

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java word count program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102754/java-word-count-program)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java word count program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102754/java-word-count-program)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would change your approach a bit. First, I would use a `BufferedReader` to read the file file in line-by-line using `readLine()`. Then split each line on whitespace using `String.split("\\s")` and use the size of the resulting array to see how many words are on that line. To get the number of characters you could either look at the size of each line or of each split word (depending of if you want to count whitespace as characters).

Answer (score 15):

You can use a Scanner with a FileInputStream instead of BufferedReader with a FileReader. For example:-

```
File file = new File("sample.txt");
try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file))){
    int count=0;
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        sc.next();
        count++;
    }
System.out.println("Number of words: " + count);
}
```

Comment: The above code gives the wrong count of words as it counts all the styles, adjustments etc.....just modify the code inside while loop with this `String word=sc.next();
      if(word.indexOf("\\")==-1)
      count++;` This will give a bit more precise count....

Comment: @SangeetMenon what do you mean? I don't understand what is meant by it counts all styles and adjustments. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 4):

This is just a thought. There is one very easy way to do it. If you just need number of words and not actual words then just use Apache WordUtils

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils;

public class CountWord {

public static void main(String[] args) {    
String str = "Just keep a boolean flag around that lets you know if the previous character was whitespace or not pseudocode follows";

    String initials = WordUtils.initials(str);

    System.out.println(initials);
    //so number of words in your file will be
    System.out.println(initials.length());    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just keep a boolean flag around that lets you know if the previous character was whitespace or not (pseudocode follows):

```
boolean prevWhitespace = false;
int wordCount = 0;
while (char ch = getNextChar(input)) {
  if (isWhitespace(ch)) {
    if (!prevWhitespace) {
      prevWhitespace = true;
      wordCount++;
    }
  } else {
    prevWhitespace = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think a correct approach would be by means of Regex:

```
String fileContent = <text from file>;    
String[] words = Pattern.compile("\\s+").split(fileContent);
System.out.println("File has " + words.length + " words");
```

Hope it helps. The "\s+" meaning is in [Pattern javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class CountWords {

    public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {

       System.out.println ("Counting Words");       
       FileReader fr = new FileReader ("c:\\Customer1.txt");        
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);     
       String line = br.readLin ();
       int count = 0;
       while (line != null) {
          String []parts = line.split(" ");
          for( String w : parts)
          {
            count++;        
          }
          line = br.readLine();
       }         
       System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember to close Reader!

Answer (score 2):

*Hack solution*

You can read the text file into a String var. Then split the String into an array using a single whitespace as the delimiter StringVar.Split(" ").

The Array count would equal the number of "Words" in the file. 
Of course this wouldnt give you a count of line numbers.

Answer (score 0):

3 steps: Consume all the white spaces, check if is a line, consume all the nonwhitespace.3

```
while(true){
    c = inFile.read();                
    // consume whitespaces
    while(isspace(c)){ inFile.read() }
    if (c == '\n'){ numberLines++; continue; }
    while (!isspace(c)){
         numberChars++;
         c = inFile.read();
    }
    numberWords++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**File Word-Count**

*If in between words having some symbols then you can split and count the number of Words.*

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File("Input.txt")));
        int count = 0;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {

            String[] s = sc.next().split("d*[.@:=#-]"); 

            for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                if (!s[i].isEmpty()){
                    System.out.println(s[i]);
                    count++;
                }   
            }           
        }
        System.out.println("Word-Count : "+count);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my solution here, it should work. The idea is to remove all the unwanted symbols from the words, then separate those words and store them in some other variable, i was using ArrayList. By adjusting the "excludedSymbols" variable you can add more symbols which you would like to be excluded from the words.

```
public static void countWords () {
    String textFileLocation ="c:\\yourFileLocation";
    String readWords ="";
    ArrayList<String> extractOnlyWordsFromTextFile = new ArrayList<>();
    // excludedSymbols can be extended to whatever you want to exclude from the file 
    String[] excludedSymbols = {" ", "," , "." , "/" , ":" , ";" , "<" , ">", "\n"};
    String readByteCharByChar = "";
    boolean testIfWord = false;


    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(textFileLocation);
        byte byte1 = (byte) inputStream.read();
        while (byte1 != -1) {

            readByteCharByChar +=String.valueOf((char)byte1);
            for(int i=0;i<excludedSymbols.length;i++) {
            if(readByteCharByChar.equals(excludedSymbols[i])) {
                if(!readWords.equals("")) {
                extractOnlyWordsFromTextFile.add(readWords);
                }
                readWords ="";
                testIfWord = true;
                break;
            }
            }
            if(!testIfWord) {
                readWords+=(char)byte1;
            }
            readByteCharByChar = "";
            testIfWord = false;
            byte1 = (byte)inputStream.read();
            if(byte1 == -1 && !readWords.equals("")) {
                extractOnlyWordsFromTextFile.add(readWords);
            }
        }
        inputStream.close();
        System.out.println(extractOnlyWordsFromTextFile);
        System.out.println("The number of words in the choosen text file are: " + extractOnlyWordsFromTextFile.size());
    } catch (IOException ioException) {

        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a very way using Java 8:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get(file))
    .flatMap(str->Stream.of(str.split("[ ,.!?\r\n]")))
    .filter(s->s.length()>0).count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader bf= new BufferedReader(new FileReader("G://Sample.txt"));
        String line=bf.readLine();
        while(line!=null)
        {
            String[] words=line.split(" ");
            System.out.println("this line contains " +words.length+ " words");
            line=bf.readLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

***The below code supports in Java 8***

//Read file into String

```
String fileContent=new String(Files.readAlBytes(Paths.get("MyFile.txt")),StandardCharacters.UFT_8);
```

//Keeping these into list of strings by splitting with a delimiter

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(contents.split("\\PL+"));

int count=0;
for(String x: words){
 if(x.length()>1) count++;
}

sop(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

So easy we can get the String from files by method: getText();

```
public class Main {

    static int countOfWords(String str) {
        if (str.equals("") || str == null) {
            return 0;
        }else{
            int numberWords = 0;
            for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
                if (c == ' ') {
                    numberWords++;
                }
            }

            return ++numberWordss;
        }
    }
}
```