# Java word count program

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program on word count which I have partially made and it is giving the correct result but the moment I enter space or more than one space in the string, the result of word count show wrong results because I am counting words on the basis of spaces used. I need help if there is a solution in a way that no matter how many spaces are I still get the correct result. I am mentioning the code below.

```
public class CountWords 
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

            System.out.println("Simple Java Word Count Program");

            String str1 = "Today is Holdiay Day";

            int wordCount = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) 
            {
                if (str1.charAt(i) == ' ') 
                {
                    wordCount++;
                } 
            }

            System.out.println("Word count is = " + wordCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

     System.out.println("Simple Java Word Count Program");

     String str1 = "Today is Holdiay Day";

     String[] wordArray = str1.trim().split("\\s+");
     int wordCount = wordArray.length;

     System.out.println("Word count is = " + wordCount);
}
```

The ideas is to split the string into words on any whitespace character occurring any number of times.
The split function of the String class returns an array containing the words as its elements.
Printing the length of the array would yield the number of words in the string.

Comment: Can you please make the program more simple with just using if else statement and for loop

Comment: I am not sure I can follow your comment.
What more simpler can this get. Introducing if-else statements and a for loop is sure going to make the program a little longer and inefficient not to mention.

Comment: Split will return array. String[] wordArray = str1.split("\\s+");

Answer (score 16):

Two routes for this. One way would be to use regular expressions. You can find out more about regular expressions [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).  A good regular expression for this would be something like "\w+" Then count the number of matches.

If you don't want to go that route, you could have a boolean flag that remembers if the last character you've seen is a space. If it is, don't count it. So the center of the loop looks like this:

```
boolean prevCharWasSpace=true;
for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) 
{
    if (str1.charAt(i) == ' ') {
        prevCharWasSpace=true;
    }
else{
        if(prevCharWasSpace) wordChar++;
        prevCharWasSpace = false;

    }
}
```

***Update***
Using the split technique is exactly equivalent to what's happening here, but it doesn't really explain why it works.  If we go back to our CS theory, we want to construct a Finite State Automa (FSA) that counts words. That FSA may appear as:
[image]

If you look at the code, it implements this FSA exactly. The prevCharWasSpace keeps track of which state we're in, and the str1.charAt('i') is decideds which edge (or arrow) is being followed. If you use the split method, a regular expression equivalent of this FSA is constructed internally, and is used to split the string into an array.

Comment: hey thanks dude it worked great but can there be any other way than using two if

Comment: this is showing wrong result.If i am putting one more space before word "day". it is showing 3.it should show 4. right sir ?

Comment: can you clarify what does this line do--  if(!prevCharWasSpace)

Comment: yes you right but you can declare the wordCount variable with the value 1

Answer (score 4):

Java does have `StringTokenizer` API and can be used for this purpose as below.

```
String test = "This is a test app";
int countOfTokens = new StringTokenizer(test).countTokens();
System.out.println(countOfTokens);
```

OR

in a single line as below

```
System.out.println(new StringTokenizer("This is a test app").countTokens());
```

`StringTokenizer` supports multiple spaces in the input string, counting only the words trimming unnecessary spaces.

```
System.out.println(new StringTokenizer("This    is    a test    app").countTokens());
```

Above line also prints 5

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.split` ([read more here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)) instead of charAt, you will get good results.
If you want to use `charAt` for some reason then try [trimming the string](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) before you count the words that way you won't have the extra space and an extra word

Comment: Trimming the string will remove whitespace at the beginning and end of a string, so the problem persists if there's multiple spaces in between words. Also, using `String.split` creates a `String[]`, so if the input is large, you'll end up using *a lot* of memory.

Comment: but wouldn't using String.split that be more efficient than going through char by char of a large string using a loop, I am not saying you are wrong, I am just asking a question

Comment: `String.split` is using a regular expression engine in the background so it's actually doing *a lot* of processing compared to a simple character-by-character iteration over a `String`. (And the return value is a `String[]` containing freshly created `String`s.) The most efficient implementation I can see here is probably along the line of @heneryville's answer. Uses hardly any extra memory and does the absolute minimum processing.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation, not using StringTokenizer:

```
Map<String, Long> getWordCounts(List<String> sentences, int maxLength) {
    Map<String, Long> commonWordsInEventDescriptions = sentences
        .parallelStream()
        .map(sentence -> sentence.replace(".", ""))
        .map(string -> string.split(" "))
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .map(s -> s.toLowerCase())
        .filter(word -> word.length() >= 2 && word.length() <= maxLength)
        .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));
    }
```

Then, you could call it like this, as an example:

```
getWordCounts(list, 9).entrySet().stream()
                .filter(pair -> pair.getValue() <= 3 && pair.getValue() >= 1)
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> 
    new RuntimeException("No matching word found.")).getKey();
```

Perhaps flipping the method to return `Map<Long, String>` might be better.

Answer (score 0):

Use `split(regex)` method.  The result is an array of strings that was splited by `regex`.

```
String s = "Today is Holdiay Day";
System.out.println("Word count is = " + s.split(" ").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.It may help you:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{

   System.out.println("Simple Java Word Count Program");

   String str1 = "Today is Holdiay Day";
   int count=0;
   String[] wCount=str1.split(" ");

   for(int i=0;i<wCount.length;i++){
        if(!wCount[i].isEmpty())
        {
            count++;
        }
   }
   System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: Your code is working great friend but can you help me getting it done by simple if else statement and for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file line by line and reduce the multiple occurences of the whitespaces appearing in your line to a single occurence and then count for the words. Following is a sample:

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {   

    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("c:\\test.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    int wordcount = 0;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
        strLine = strLine.replaceAll("[\t\b]", "");
        strLine = strLine.replaceAll(" {2,}", " ");
        if (!strLine.isEmpty()){
            wordcount = wordcount + strLine.split(" ").length;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(wordcount);
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: I just want it to be done by simple if else statement and for loop

Comment: In that case take a look at @heneryville 's suggestion. You can check for all whitespaces as against just the space.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class CountWords 
    {
        public static void main (String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Simple Java Word Count Program");
            String str1 = "Today is Holdiay Day";
            int wordCount = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) 
            {
                if (str1.charAt(i) == ' ' && str1.charAt(i+1)!=' ') 
                {
                    wordCount++;
                } 
            }
            System.out.println("Word count is = " + wordCount));
        }
    }
```

This gives the correct result because if space comes twice or more then it can't increase wordcount. Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class wordCOunt
{
public static void main(String ar[])
{
System.out.println("Simple Java Word Count Program");

    String str1 = "Today is Holdiay Day";

    int wordCount = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) 
    {
        if (str1.charAt(i) == ' '&& str1.charAt(i+1)!=' ') 
        {
            wordCount++;
        } 
    }

    System.out.println("Word count is = " +(str1.length()- wordCount));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class wordCount
{
public static void main(String ar[]) throws Exception
{
System.out.println("Simple Java Word Count Program");


    int wordCount = 1,count=1;
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/file.txt"));
            String str2 = "", str1 = "";

            while ((str1 = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    str2 += str1;

            }


    for (int i = 0; i < str2.length(); i++) 
    {
        if (str2.charAt(i) == ' ' && str2.charAt(i+1)!=' ') 
        {
            wordCount++;
        } 


        }

    System.out.println("Word count is = " +(wordCount));
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> you should make your code more generic by considering other word separators as well.. such as "," ";" etc.

```
public class WordCounter{
    public int count(String input){
        int count =0;
        boolean incrementCounter = false;
        for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i++){
            if (isValidWordCharacter(input.charAt(i))){
                incrementCounter = true;
            }else if (incrementCounter){
                count++;
                incrementCounter = false;
            }
        }
        if (incrementCounter) count ++;//if string ends with a valid word
        return count;
    }
    private boolean isValidWordCharacter(char c){
        //any logic that will help you identify a valid character in a word
        // you could also have a method which identifies word separators instead of this
        return (c >= 'A' && c<='Z') || (c >= 'a' && c<='z'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import com.google.common.collect.Multiset;

String str="Simple Java Word Count count Count Program";
Iterable<String> words = Splitter.on(" ").trimResults().split(str);


//google word counter       
Multiset<String> wordsMultiset = HashMultiset.create();
for (String string : words) {   
    wordsMultiset.add(string.toLowerCase());
}

Set<String> result = wordsMultiset.elementSet();
for (String string : result) {
    System.out.println(string+" X "+wordsMultiset.count(string));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int CountWords(String str){

   if(str.length() == 0)
          return 0;

   int count =0;
   for(int i=0;i< str.length();i++){


      if(str(i) == ' ')
          continue;

      if(i > 0 && str.charAt(i-1) == ' '){
        count++;
      } 

      else if(i==0 && str.charAt(i) != ' '){
       count++;
      }


   }
   return count;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String data = "This world is mine";
    System.out.print(data.split("\\s+").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
public class wordcount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "India is my country. I love India";
        List<String> qw = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, Integer> mmm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        for (String sp : s.split(" ")) {
            qw.add(sp);
        }
        for (String num : qw) {
            mmm.put(num, Collections.frequency(qw, num));
        }
        System.out.println(mmm);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To count total words Or to count total words without repeat word count

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String test = "I am trying to make make make";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    HashSet<String> hs =  new HashSet<>();
    int i=0;
    while (m.find()) {
        i++;
        hs.add(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println("Total words Count==" + i);
    System.out.println("Count without Repetation ==" + hs.size());
}
```

}

Output :

Total words Count==7

Count without Repeatation ==5

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a drawback, but this worked for me...

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = input.nextLine();
    String trimmed = userInput.trim();
    int count = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < trimmed.length(); i++) {
      if ((trimmed.charAt(i) == ' ') && (trimmed.charAt(i-1) != ' ')) {
        count++;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be as simple as using split and count variable.

```
public class SplitString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count=0;        
        String s1="Hi i love to code";

        for(String s:s1.split(" "))
        {
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class TotalWordsInSentence {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "This is sample sentence";
        int NoOfWOrds = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i<str.length();i++){
            if ((str.charAt(i) == ' ') && (i!=0) && (str.charAt(i-1) != ' ')){
                NoOfWOrds++;
            }
        }
         System.out.println("Number of Words in Sentence: " + NoOfWOrds);
    }
}
```

In this code, There wont be any problem regarding white-space in it.
just the simple for loop. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

To count specified words only like John, John99, John_John and John's only. Change regex according to yourself and count the specified words only.

```
    public static int wordCount(String content) {
        int count = 0;
        String regex = "([a-zA-Z_’][0-9]*)+[\\s]*";     
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            count++;
            System.out.println(matcher.group().trim()); //If want to display the matched words
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

class HelloWorld {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str = "User is in for an interview";
int counter=0;
String arrStr[] = str.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i< arrStr.length; i++){
        String charStr = arrStr[i];
        for(int j=0; j<charStr.length(); j++) {
            if(charStr.charAt(j) =='i') {
              counter++;
            }
       }
    }
    System.out.println("i " + counter);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CountWords {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the string :");
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("length is string is :"+str.length());
        int worldCount = 1;
        for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
            if(str.charAt(i) == ' '){
                worldCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(worldCount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The full program working is:

```
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        logicCounter counter1 = new logicCounter();
        counter1.counter("I am trying to make a program on word count which I have partially made and it is giving the correct result but the moment I enter space or more than one space in the string, the result of word count show wrong results because I am counting words on the basis of spaces used. I need help if there is a solution in a way that no matter how many spaces are I still get the correct result. I am mentioning the code below.");
    }
}

public class logicCounter {

    public void counter (String str) {

        String str1 = str;
        boolean space= true;
        int i;

        for ( i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++) {

            if (str1.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                space=true;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("there are " + i + " letters");
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to count letters rather than words, the OP requested word count instead.