# write a method to return number of words in a string? edited

Tags: java

Write a method called wordCount that accepts a String as its parameter and returns the number of words in the String. A word is a sequence of one or more nonspace characters (any character other than ' '). For example, the call wordCount("hello") should return 1, the call wordCount("how are you?") should return 3, the call wordCount(" this     string has     wide       spaces ") should return 5, and the call wordCount(" ") should return 0.

ok so my problem is that when a string/phrase word input by the program begins
with a space rather than a word, it doesn't register the following words in the sentence and returns value 1.

so if the wordCount is("   this string    has   wide spaces")
which should return 5 but  is only retiring 0. i don't get why can you help me understand where i messed up?

here is my method:

```
   public static int wordCount(String s) {
          int word = 0;
          if(s!=null)
          if(s.charAt(0)!=' ') {
              word++;
          }
          for(int i=0; i<=s.length(); i++) 
          {
          if(s.charAt(i)!=' ' && s.charAt(i+1) ==' ') 
          {
                word++;
          }
              return word;
        }
           return word;
    }
```

Comment: A `char` cannot be compared to an empty `String`, as the error says. Did you intend to check if the character was a space? `s.charAt(0) != ' '`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102754/java-word-count-program First hit on google: "java word count"

Comment: @Andreas 
yes I want it to see if there is a space and skip it, so that will only count the words and not include spaces in the count. Whenever I change "" to '' i get even more error notifications...

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static int wordCount(String s) {
     if(s!=null)
       return s.trim().split(" ").length ;
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by defining **done**. Usually, that's when your functional definition is complete. One such example (from your question), might look something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] inputs = { "hello", "how are you?",
            " this string has wide spaces ", " " };
    int[] outputs = { 1, 3, 5, 0 };
    String[] inputs = { "hello", "how are you?",
            " this string has wide spaces ", " " };
    int[] outputs = { 1, 3, 5, 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < outputs.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("Expected: %d, Actual: %d, %s%n",
                wordCount(inputs[i]), outputs[i],
                wordCount(inputs[i]) == outputs[i] ? "Pass" : "Fail");
    }
}
```

Your `wordCount` method needs to account for `null`. Next you can use [`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) to create a token array. All you're interested in is its' length. Something like

```
public static int wordCount(String s) {
    String t = (s == null) ? "" : s.trim();
    return t.isEmpty() ? 0 : t.split("\\s+").length;
}
```

It passes your provided test conditions, generating the output

```
Expected: 1, Actual: 1, Pass
Expected: 3, Actual: 3, Pass
Expected: 5, Actual: 5, Pass
Expected: 1, Actual: 1, Pass
```