# How to word count a set of files within a directory using Java 8 in lambda form

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I'm working on a assignment in which the program reads a directory and gets the number of files in the directory. However, the program also has to perform a word count within each file. Moreover, the program must use Java 8 Streams and use Lambda syntax.

The questions:

How would you use to count the words within a set of undetermined files in a directory? I can't just type a specific file name, though the program knows what directory to look in.

Would you use FileStream? a Map? BOTH?

This is what I've done so far. However, it only counts the files in the directory and outputs the result:

fileCatch8.java :

```
public class fileCatch8 {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
     List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
      DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream
        (Paths.get("files"));
      for (Path path : directoryStream) {
        fileNames.add(path.toString());
      }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    System.out.println("Count: "+fileNames.size() + " files");
  }
}
```

wordCount8 :

```
public class wordCount {
    public static Map<String, Integer> countJava8Style(String input) {
    return Pattern.compile("\\W+")
                  .splitAsStream(input)
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::toLowerCase,
                                                 Collectors.summingInt(s -> 1)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094119/counting-number-of-words-in-a-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8102754/java-word-count-program) there are many different ways to implement it...

Comment: @alfasin What I mean is: This program must find a file blind, so you can't just type in a specific text file, then count the files' contents. Then it would be simple to do a println like (Example: word length: 1 ==> 80). That is what's stumping me.

Comment: @alfasin Also, I did checked that link to "Word count with java 8", but the code had specific parameters, whereas  I'm writing something that checks to see what's there are how many words for each file.

Comment: @alfasin On second thought . . . Let me look at that article again. Thank you sir.