# Reading from a txt file

Tags: java

I wrote a method that adds 1 to an `int` called `total` each time it sees a new word:

```
public int GetTotal() throws FileNotFoundException{
    int total = 0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Particles/Names.txt")));
    while(s.hasNext()){
        if(s.hasNext()){
            total++;
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Is that the right way to write it?

Comment: Does it compile?  How have you tried to test it?

Comment: Better way to do it here. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4094186/628943

Comment: The problem is, this would have an infinite loop. Consider the metaphor of looking if a customer is waiting to be serviced, but you never actually service them.

Comment: the hasNext method does not read the word from the Scanner s.  You must call the next method to read the word from the scanner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks fine. But the `inner IF` is unnecessary, also the `next()` method is required. Below should be fine.

```
public int GetTotal() throws FileNotFoundException{
    int total = 0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Particles/Names.txt")));
    while(s.hasNext()){
            s.next();
            total++;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: You can always use a regular expression as a parameter in hasNext() as seen in my answer.

Comment: @Jayamohan review it again and see what is the problem.
you ma double check It.

Answer (score 2):

The Scanner implements Iterator.You should at least make the iterator step forward, like this:

```
public int GetTotal() throws FileNotFoundException{
int total = 0;
Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Particles/Names.txt")));
while(s.hasNext()){
        s.next();
        total++;
}
return total;
```

}

or the loop will run infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to match all non-whitespace. :-)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScanWords {

 public ScanWords() throws FileNotFoundException {
   Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("path/to/file.txt"));
   int wordCount = 0;
   while (scan.hasNext("\\S+")) {
     scan.next();
     wordCount++;
   }
   System.out.printf("Word Count: %d", wordCount);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new ScanWords();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you have an infinite loop. Also there is a much simpler way to use Scanner.

```
    int total = 0;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("/usr/share/dict/words"));

    while(s.hasNext()){
        s.next();
        total++;
    }
    return total;
```